# Radon-Nikodym on a Process wrt to filtration

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. Let $(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ be a stochastic process defined on it with cadlag paths, lets say on $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{B}(X))$.
Let be $\mathcal{F}_{t}$ be the natural filtration of $(X_t)$. Assume that $Q$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure on $\mathcal{F}_t$ for each $t\geq 0$. Denote $P^t$ the restriction of $P$ to $\mathcal{F}_t$.
Then by Radon-Nikodym on $\mathcal{F}_t$ is defined by
$$
L(\mathcal{F}_t)(\omega)=\frac{dP^{t}}{dQ^{t}}(\omega) \tag 1
$$
on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ and this expression is $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable.
Note this is a martingale so for $s<t$ we have $\mathcal{F}_s\subseteq \mathcal{F}_t$
and thus
$$
L(\mathcal{F}_s)=E_{Q}[L(\mathcal{F}_t)|\mathcal{F}_s]
$$
Let $X:=(X_s)_{s\in[0,t]}$ be the trajectory on $[0,t]$. Then we have with the pushforward measure/induced measure $P^{X}$ on $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{B}(X))$ the equality
$$
L(\mathcal{F}_t)(\omega)=\frac{dP^{t}}{dQ^{t}}(\omega)=\frac{dP^{X}}{dQ^{X}} (X(\omega))\quad Q-a.s.
$$
by theorem of measure transformation.

How is this setup change, when we take the right continuous filtration $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}_t=\bigcap_{s>t}\sigma(X_u:u\leq s)$. This is often done in statistical inference for stochastic processes. Lets define the radon nikodym derivative like above with respect to this filtration. Can we get a representation of $L(\tilde{\mathcal{F}}_t)$ analogous to the one above?
Is
$$
L(\tilde{\mathcal{F}}_t)(\omega)=\frac{dP^{X(\omega)}}{dQ^{X(\omega)}} \tag2
$$
still valid? Note $X_t$ is cadlag. 
Or is this defined otherwise?

In many applications (change of measure theory of stochastic processes) the likelihood-functions i've seen coincide.

Best regards

Comment: Well unless mistaken in general in stochastic process theory, you suppose that "usual hypothesis" hold over the filtration (even for filtration adapted to a process), so taking the right continuous versions is harmless. Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge Ok, but generally we just can define (1) for the natural filtration with the equality in (1) where $X$ is a cadlag process . Sometimes the filtration of our process is not rightcontinuous so we have to make it rightcontinous for some applications. So we can think of that the likelihoodratio $L(\tilde{\mathcal{F}}_t)$ as the restriction of $P$ wrt to $Q$ on $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}_t$ is of the form (2)?

Comment: just remove the "just can" in the first sentence. can not edit it anymore